# Update Laravel Scout (Algolia) without database

Tags: php, laravel, model, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm fetching data from Airtable and converting this to an Eloquent Model.

Is there a way to send this Model to Algolia without first storing it in a MySql DB?

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
php artisan scout:import "<your model path>"
```

e.g. `php artisan scout:import "App\Product"`